# What occurrs in a 'for loop' at the hardware level? Is memory automatically assigned? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, memory, char

I have some code here which reverses an array of characters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char s[50];

void reverseChar(char * s)
{
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(s)/2; ++i)
    {
        char temp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[strlen(s)-i-1];
        s[strlen(s)-i-1] = temp;
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, this program reverses words." << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter in a word, no spaces please:" << endl;
    cin.getline(s, 50);
    cout << "This is the word, it has now been reversed:" << endl;
    reverseChar(s);
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

In the for loop can someone explain what is going on at the hardware level. I understand 'temp' is allocated to a byte, which is assigned to the value of s[i].

Is memory allocated to everything?

The equals sign, s[i], etc?

After the byte is assigned to the value in s[i], s[i] is assigned to some other value in array s. This other value is then assigned to temp.

I'm having trouble understanding where all these bytes are going, and how they are being manipulated by C++.

I understand that in the line:

```
s[i] = s[strlen(s)-i-1];
```

The placeholder values are being swapped?

In this line:

```
s[strlen(s)-i-1] = temp;
```

The 'copied' value is sent to 'temp'. But what happens to this temp value afterwards, does it become the new 'temp' once the for loop reiterates?

Comment: You need to take a course on computer architecture, and on how compilers work. :)

Comment: So why do you want to know all those low level details?

Comment: @user3528438 Are you being sarcastic? The OP isn't asking about "low-level details," although he thinks he is.  He's actually showing a distinct lack of understanding of how C++ syntax works and, as Lightness points out, how C++ code is translated into machine code (a basic understanding of which is essential to effectively using any compiled language).  Nothing that more study won't clear up.

Comment: A couple of side notes: 1. Declaring variable `s` as global is a bad idea in this case (and in general, unless you really need it to be). In any case, if it's global then you don't need to pass it to the function, and moreover, using a local variable with the same name makes your code even less readable.

Comment: (continued:) In the function scope, the compiler will prefer the local variable over the global variable, and since you are calling the function with the global variable it's not going to make a difference even if the compiler chose the global variable, nevertheless, the whole thing seems pointless. Just declare the variable inside function `main` and pass it to other functions when needed. 2. You are calling `strlen(s)` 3 times inside the `for` loop. Call it once before the loop, and use the returned value.

Comment: @barakmanos I see what you mean, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In the for loop can someone explain what is going on at the hardware
>   level. I understand 'temp' is allocated to a byte, which is assigned
>   to the value of s[i].
>
> Is memory allocated to everything?

Yes, it is allocated, but on the stack. You need to learn the difference between stack and heap.

Yes, all variables are represented in some form of memory. But then again, based on the context, it could be either a stack or a heap.

> The equals sign, s[i], etc?

Equals is an operator, to inform the compiler that an assignment operation is taking place, so no memory is required for that.
s[i], on the other hand, is an array object, represented in the stack memory.

> The 'mirrored' value is sent to 'temp'. But what happens to this temp
>   value afterwards, does it become the new 'temp' once the for loop
>   reiterates?

since, in the loop you have declared temp as,

```
char temp;
```

a new variable temp, is created in the stack for every iteration.

I strongly recommend that you read about memory organization in a typical operating system. You can start with the basics from [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/).

Edit: Also note that based on the scope of the variable, the compiler automatically de-allocates memory for a stack variable based on its scope. For the temp variable above, its scope ends at the end of for loop, and hence it is destroyed at that point. Hence the compiler does not end up allocating a character space of memory for every iteration.

Comment: Everything here is correct. Just as a minor clarification, the stack space does not grow with every iteration of the loop. The compiler is smart enough to reuse the same memory address on the stack to store `temp` for each loop iteration.

Comment: True, clarified that part